# Ошибка: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_member'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Пишу бота и мне нужно получать ник с айди пользователя, поискал немного в интернете и понял, что нужно писать вроде `guild.get_member(id)`, но выдаёт ошибку:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_member'

Сделал для этого тестовую команду:

```
@commands.command()
async def test(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
    id = member.id
    print(id)
    guild = client.get_guild(ctx.message.guild.id)
    member2 = guild.get_member(id)
    print(member2)
```

. Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 2):

[Данные о пользователе](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_user) по его id:

```
await fetch_user(user_id)]
```

Функция вернет [объект User](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User)